# Iterate over a subtree of a (mutable) filesystem

Tags: java

**Introduction**

I need to create an iterator over a filesystem subtree (e.g. an iterator that would, given a folder, return all files contained inside, in a depth-first-search order, one at every `next` method call).

The contents of the subtree can change over time, e.g. it is possible (and probable) that, while the iteration is still in progress, new subfolders and files will get created and some of the existing ones will get deleted.

Fortunatelly the following conditions are acceptable:

- the implementation can (but it would be better if it did not) skip newly created files (e.g. files that originated after the iteration started) and folders (and files in those folders), or even just some of them,
- the implementation can (but it would be better if it did not) list deleted files (e.g. files that no longer exist but were present when the iteration started), or even just some of them.

---

**Motivation**

In order to give you a better insight into the rationals behind those decisions, I'd like to briefly describe the application as a whole.

It is a producer/consumer -like application. A web service (the producer) would accept files and store them on a local filesystem, somewhere in the subtree hierarchy.

Another application (the consumer) would process these files. It would be invoked periodically via CRON every few minutes. When launched, it would crawl the subtree, find all documents, and hand them over to be processed (to yet another application, if that's relevant). After a document is processed, it gets deleted from the local filesystem.

The problem is that the producer and the consumer would be running at the same time. Moreover, multiple instances of the consumer application might be running at the same time as well. E.g. while a consumer is crawling the subtree, new documents might get created and existing documents might get deleted. Even the structure of subdirectories might get modified.

Because the crawler gets launched periodically every few minutes, it does not matter if it consumes all the documents available at the time (especially those produced while the consumer is running). It is only important that a produced document gets eventually consumed (with a reasonably small delay). That's where the relaxing conditions listed above come from.

---

**Possible solutions**

I first thought I would create a snapshot of the subtree into memory at launch time (e.g. the list of documents to be processed) and then iterate over them. See [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877288/iterator-over-a-snapshot-of-a-filesystem-subtree/13877974#13877974). But the hierarchy might be very large (even tens of thousands of documents processed per a few hours) and I was thinking that this approach might have unacceptable performace demands (memory & speed).

---

**How would you implement such an iterator?**

---

Thanks very much for your help and sorry for the big length of the post.

Comment: Maybe (non-recursively) copy only the subdirectory that you are into?

Comment: @bowmore: No, unfortunately Java 1.5 compatibility has to be achieved. I would appreciate suggestions on how this could be solved in Java 1.7 as well though (because of curiosity and to learn).

Comment: @bowmore In Java 7 it's very easy. [java.nio.file.FileSystem.getRootDirectories()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) + java.nio.file.Path.iterator(). [Overview of the FileSystem API](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/file-system-api-428204.pdf)

Comment: @ignis I know, that's why I asked

Comment: @Dusan. Another idea is using database transactions.

Comment: @ginis Could you elaborate more on the database transactions, please? How exactly could I use them? Thank you

Comment: @Dusan, a transaction is an atomic operation, like a Java synchronized() statement. When you need a thread safe Map, you only access it inside synchronized() blocks (Collections.synchronizedMap hides that for you), right? Similarly, a database gives an application-independent list of string-blob mappings, using only transactions makes it thread safe.

Comment: @ignis But I'm processing files on a hard drive, not rows in a database.

Comment: Sorry then, I thought that you were also working on the producer, and could change it to write to a database. Some file systems (ZFS, if I recall correctly) also have support for transactions.

Comment: Switching to a DBMS would seem ideal to me. Sadly, I am not in position to make this decision. It cannot be done as there is a wide infrastructure around already that counts on this method of handing over of documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot use JDK 7 directly you may still look at how they did it there : [FileTreeWalker](http://j7a.ru/_file_tree_walker_8java_source.html)